# problem with post in API twitter using PHP library

Tags: php, twitter

Im trying to use the following PHP to add a favorite to my account:

```
$favorite = $connection->post('favorites/create/'.$id);
```

where `$id` is the status id but favorite don't return nothing also I'm trying with statuses/retweet/ but is the same

Comment: the library is twitteroauth - @abraham's Twitter OAuth library for PHP

Answer (score 0):

Replace the period with a comma, right before $id:

```
$favorite = $connection->get('favorites/create',$id);
```

Comment: I did this but return the same NULL

Comment: sorry I forget the last slash but the return is object(stdClass)#28 (2) { ["error"]=> string(27) "This method requires a GET." ["request"]=> string(24) "/1/favorites/create.json" } stdClass Object ( [error] => This method requires a GET. [request] => /1/favorites/create.json ) in the documentation the method is POST

Comment: oops, replace the "post", with "get" as I did

Answer (score 0):

Also when you are debugging, use print_r($favorite); to help you. Saved me with my problem today actually :-) But Andre is correct, remove the fullstop.

Comment: I use var_dump and the return is NULL